# vspace gets extremely large

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, rules

I'm just writing my bachelor thesis and i got into some problems with vspace.
To seperate definitions, theorems and so on, from the rest of the text i defined the following environment:

```
\newenvironment{myblock}{%
\vspace{.5\baselineskip}
\hrule\nopagebreak\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}\nopagebreak}
{\nopagebreak\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}\nopagebreak\hrule\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}}
```

and this environment for definitions:

```
\newcounter{definition}[section]
\renewcommand*\thedefinition{\thesection.\arabic{definition}}
\newenvironment{definition}{%
\refstepcounter{definition}
\begin{myblock}
\textbf{Definition \thedefinition}
}
{\end{myblock}}
```

In some cases the vspace bevore and after the `hrule`s become extremly large. Since I don't know the reason for this behaviour I'm not able to create an MWE. However, I tried to remove the `\nopagebreak` commands and replaced the
\baselineskip by a precise number of pt. None of this solved the problem.

Does anyone here know the reason, or even better a possibility to resolve this problem?

EDIT: Here is an example picture, the space between the hrule and the line should be `.5\baselineskip`:

[image: exmaplepicture]

Comment: Did you try `\raggedbottom` in your preamble, instead of the default `\flushbottom`? On another hand, to separate theorem-like structures from ordinary text, you'd better use a dedicated package such as `ntheorem`.

Comment: I think that you should use the features of `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` for defining “ruled theorems”.

Comment: I just tried `\raggedbottom` and it solved my problem. Either anyway I will try the packaged you suggested, because I think, that that would be a cleaner solution. Thanks for the quick help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should use `mdframed` instead of that handmade version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfdefinestyle{ruledtheorem}{
  topline=true,
  bottomline=true,
  leftline=false,
  rightline=false,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=.5\baselineskip,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
}

\newmdtheoremenv[
  style=ruledtheorem,
]{lemma}{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  style=ruledtheorem,
]{definition}[lemma]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{definition}
A pig is called a \emph{flypig} if it can fly.
\end{definition}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{lemma}
Flypigs exist.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]